# pandas optimal way to do element-wise comparison between two series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas series:

`s1` with potentially a very large number of rows and some `NaN` and `s2` (which is a column in a dataframe (`df`) with only 20 rows.
The index of the two series differ.

```
s1:

id
1      4.5
2     15.0
3     13.0
4     14.0
5     18.0
6     15.0
7     13.0
8     14.0
9      NaN
10     NaN
11     NaN
12    18.0
13     NaN
14     NaN
15     NaN


df:

      col1    s2   
0     20.0    0.0
1     19.0    4.5
2     18.0    5.0
3     17.0    6.0
4     16.0    7.0
5     15.0    8.0
6     14.0    9.0
7     13.0   10.0
8     12.0   11.0
9     11.0   12.0
10    10.0   13.0
11     9.0   15.0
12     8.0   16.0
13     7.0   18.0
14     6.0   20.0
15     5.0   22.0
16     4.0   24.0
17     3.0   26.0
18     2.0   28.0
19     1.0  100.0
```

For each `id` of `s1` I want to retrieve the value of `col1` for the first element in `s2` smaller or equal to `id`.

i.e. for `id 1` we have `s1 = 4.5`, which is smaller or equal than `df.s2 = 4.5`, hence I want to retrieve the value `19`.
Accordingly, for `id=2` in `s1` I need to retrieve the value `9` in `df.col1`

This is my current solution. I am wondering if there is a better (faster, maybe a pandas function?)  way to get the same result:

```
      output =  [min(df[df['s2'].le(element)].col1, default = np.NaN) for element in s1]

[19.0,
 9.0,
 10.0,
 10.0,
 7.0,
 9.0,
 10.0,
 10.0,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 7.0,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan]
```

Comment: Some problem with solution ?

Comment: @jezrael. Yes, was preparing a detailed comment =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is use numpy and compare each value from column by each value of `Series` for 2d array, then pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), set `NaN` if no match and last use [`numpy.nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html):

```
m = df['s2'].to_numpy() <= s1.to_numpy()[:, None]

a = np.nanmin(np.where(m, df['col1'], np.nan), axis=1)
print (a)
[19.  9. 10. 10.  7.  9. 10. 10. nan nan nan  7. nan nan nan]
```

**Performance**: original sample

```
In [63]: %%timeit
    ...: [min(df[df['s2'].le(element)].col1, default = np.NaN) for element in s1]
    ...: 
    ...: 
9.21 ms ± 305 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [64]: %%timeit
    ...: m = df['s2'].to_numpy() <= s1.to_numpy()[:, None]
    ...: a = np.nanmin(np.where(m, df['col1'], np.nan), axis=1)
72.4 µs ± 870 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Larger data 100 times:

```
#2k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 100, ignore_index=True)
#1.5k rows
s1 = pd.concat([s1] * 100, ignore_index=True)


In [68]: %%timeit
    ...: [min(df[df['s2'].le(element)].col1, default = np.NaN) for element in s1]
    ...: 
    ...: 
1.12 s ± 17.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [69]: %%timeit
    ...: m = df['s2'].to_numpy() <= s1.to_numpy()[:, None]
    ...: a = np.nanmin(np.where(m, df['col1'], np.nan), axis=1)
34.2 ms ± 305 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great answer as always. Unfortunely I get the following two warnings: `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal` when running `m = df['s2'].to_numpy() <= s1.to_numpy()[:, None]`  and `RuntimeWarning: All-NaN slice encountered` when running `a = np.nanmin(np.where(m, df['col1'], np.nan), axis=1)`. The result is also incorrect: `a=array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,
       nan, nan])`

Comment: I am using numpy==1.18.2 (not sure if that's relevant). pandas==1.0.3

Comment: @Gio - I test it in pandas 1.01, so yes, it is version dependent.

Comment: Little update, the solution works correctly. I am not sure why the result was not working (maybe I messed up something while testing). I still get the two warnings but I believe that won't cause any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use interval index.

First the data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [
            4.5,
            15.0,
            13.0,
            14.0,
            18.0,
            15.0,
            13.0,
            14.0,
            np.nan,
            np.nan,
            np.nan,
            18.0,
            np.nan,
            np.nan,
            np.nan,
        ]
    ),
    columns=["s1"],
)
print(df1)
       s1
0   4.500
1  15.000
2  13.000
3  14.000
4  18.000
5  15.000
6  13.000
7  14.000
8     nan
9     nan
10    nan
11 18.000
12    nan
13    nan
14    nan
```

Then the lookup dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "col1": {
            0: 20.0,
            1: 19.0,
            2: 18.0,
            3: 17.0,
            4: 16.0,
            5: 15.0,
            6: 14.0,
            7: 13.0,
            8: 12.0,
            9: 11.0,
            10: 10.0,
            11: 9.0,
            12: 8.0,
            13: 7.0,
            14: 6.0,
            15: 5.0,
            16: 4.0,
            17: 3.0,
            18: 2.0,
            19: 1.0,
        },
        "end": {
            0: 0.0,
            1: 4.5,
            2: 5.0,
            3: 6.0,
            4: 7.0,
            5: 8.0,
            6: 9.0,
            7: 10.0,
            8: 11.0,
            9: 12.0,
            10: 13.0,
            11: 15.0,
            12: 16.0,
            13: 18.0,
            14: 20.0,
            15: 22.0,
            16: 24.0,
            17: 26.0,
            18: 28.0,
            19: 100.0,
        },
    }
)
print(df)
    col1     end
0  20.000   0.000
1  19.000   4.500
2  18.000   5.000
3  17.000   6.000
4  16.000   7.000
5  15.000   8.000
6  14.000   9.000
7  13.000  10.000
8  12.000  11.000
9  11.000  12.000
10 10.000  13.000
11  9.000  15.000
12  8.000  16.000
13  7.000  18.000
14  6.000  20.000
15  5.000  22.000
16  4.000  24.000
17  3.000  26.000
18  2.000  28.000
19  1.000 100.000
```

Make a start column to create the interval, fill the first row with zero.

```
df["start"] = df["end"].shift().fillna(0)
print(df.head())
    col1   end  start
0 20.000 0.000  0.000
1 19.000 4.500  0.000
2 18.000 5.000  4.500
3 17.000 6.000  5.000
4 16.000 7.000  6.000
```

Create an interval index and set as index.

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df["start"], df["end"], closed="right")
df.index = idx
print(df.head())
             col1   end  start
(0.0, 0.0] 20.000 0.000  0.000
(0.0, 4.5] 19.000 4.500  0.000
(4.5, 5.0] 18.000 5.000  4.500
(5.0, 6.0] 17.000 6.000  5.000
(6.0, 7.0] 16.000 7.000  6.000
```

Final result

```
df1.loc[df1.dropna().index, "col1"] = df.loc[df1.loc[:, "s1"].dropna(), "col1"].values

print(df1)
      s1   col1
0   4.500 19.000
1  15.000  9.000
2  13.000 10.000
3  14.000  9.000
4  18.000  7.000
5  15.000  9.000
6  13.000 10.000
7  14.000  9.000
8     nan    nan
9     nan    nan
10    nan    nan
11 18.000  7.000
12    nan    nan
13    nan    nan
14    nan    nan
```

Full code without printouts.

```
df["start"] = df["end"].shift().fillna(0)

idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df["start"], df["end"], closed="right")
df.index = idx

df1.loc[df1.dropna().index, "col1"] = df.loc[df1.loc[:, "s1"].dropna(), "col1"].values
```